# No configuration and trained data-files in case of Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have installed Tesseract OCR on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

and the basic usage is working well. But when I look for the configuration and training files which are supposed to be in the `/usr/local/share/tessdata` folder, I cannot find such a directory on my system. Did I misunderstand that this is automatically created at installation and I'm supposed to create by hand?

Answer (score 0):

The training tools are built separately.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract#building-the-training-tools